# apoc.periodic.iterate not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to create a `List` then add a relationship with very large number of data. So I'm trying to use `apoc.periodic.iterate` as like as given below:

```
CREATE (pl:List {id: 'some-random-id-01', title:'title-01'})

 WITH pl as pl

 CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('
    MATCH (p:DbLists)
       WHERE p.name CONTAINS "name"
    RETURN p.id as Ids
    SKIP 0 LIMIT 10000
 ', '
   WITH {pl} as pl
     UNWIND Ids as Id
       MATCH (p:DbInfos {id: Id})
         WITH p as cn
          SET cn :Contacts
           WITH cn as cn
           MERGE (pl)-[cnpt:CONTACTS_LISTING  { email: cn.email } ]->(cn)
        RETURN pl
      ', 
      { batchSize:100, parallel:true, pl:pl } 
    ) YIELD batches

    return pl, batches
```

In above query, first I have create a `List`, then find  `10000` data from `DbLists` where `DbLists.name CONTAINS "name-01"` and **return** `id`. And now `CREATE` a relationship with `DbInfos` using the `id` of `DbLists`.

Lastly return `pl, batches`.

And My output is value of `pl` and `100` for `batches`. But when I explore my database, I have only found `List` data, but none of any others data like `Contacts, CONTACTS_LISTING(relationship)` etc.

Sample Data:

**DbLists::**

```
[{
   id: 'some-id-01',
   name: 'some name 01',
   email: 'email1@gmail.com'
}, {
   id: 'some-id-02',
   name: 'some name 02',
   email: 'email2@gmail.com'
},{ 
    id: 'some-id-03',
   name: 'some name 03',
   email: 'email3@gmail.com'
},{
    id: 'some-id-04',
   name: 'some namex 04',
   email: 'email4@gmail.com'
},
......................
.........................
]
```

**DbInfos::**

```
[
 {
   id: 'list-id-01',
   name: 'some name 01',
   email: 'email1@gmail.com'
  }, {
   id: 'list-id-02',
   name: 'some name 02',
   email: 'email2@gmail.com'
},{ 
   id: 'list-id-03',
   name: 'some name 03',
   email: 'email3@gmail.com'
},{
   id: 'list-id-04',
   name: 'some name 04',
   email: 'email4@gmail.com'
}
]
```

**Desired Results::**

```
            List { {id: 'some-random-id-01', title:'title-01'}  }
          /         \
         /           \
    C_L {eml1}      C_L {eml2}  
       /               \
DbInfos::Contacts      DbInfos::Contacts {}
{ id: 'list-id-01',               { id: 'list-id-02',
 email: 'email1@gmail.com'           email: 'email2@gmail.com'}
 }
....................................
....................................
```

Here:

```
C_L = CONTACTS_LISTING
eml1 = 'email1@gmail.com' 
eml2 = 'email2@gmail.com'
```

Here `DbInfos` and `DbLists` have same labels.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: pass `params: {pl : pl}` instead

Answer (score 0):

I see the possible problems in that you do not pass the variable `pl` below, and create a relationship without being sure that the `cn.email` property exists:

```
...
WITH cn as cn
MERGE (pl)-[cnpt:CONTACTS_LISTING  { email: cn.email } ]->(cn)
...
```

Try changing the inner statement to this:

```
WITH {pl} as pl
  UNWIND {Ids} as Id
    MATCH (cn:DbInfos {id: Id}) SET cn :Contacts
    MERGE (pl)-[cnpt:CONTACTS_LISTING]->(cn) SET cnpt.email = cn.email     
RETURN pl
```

Comment: I have change code as like as you said, it has created list, but no data created on `Contacts` and `Contacts`

Comment: @sabbir I think you need to showing the sample of the input data and describing the desired result.

Comment: please you take a look.

Comment: @sabbir In your example, the nodes ":DbLists" and "DbInfos" have completely different properties "". Give an example with the correct data.

Comment: @sabbir These data do not correlate with the cypher-query. On them it is impossible to understand what is wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `UNWIND Ids as Id MATCH (p:DbInfos {id: Id})` isn't correct cause you have absolutly different ids in DbInfo and DbLists. So you will never find a node with {id: Id} in p:DbInfos.

I've corrected your query and tested it. So this must work.

1. create List
   `CREATE (pl:List {id: 'some-random-id-01', title:'title-01'})`
2. do next:

`CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('
     MATCH (p:DbLists)
     WHERE p.name CONTAINS "name"
     RETURN collect(p.id) as Ids
     SKIP 0 LIMIT 10000 
', '
     MATCH (pl:List {id: \'some-random-id-01\', title:\'title-01\'})
     WITH pl as pl
     UNWIND {Ids} as Id MATCH (p:DbInfos {id: Id})
     SET p:Contacts 
     WITH p,pl
     MERGE (pl)-[cnpt:CONTACTS_LISTING  { email: p.email } ]->(p)
     RETURN pl 
', { batchSize:100, parallel:true} 
    ) YIELD batches
MATCH p=()-[r:CONTACTS_LISTING]->() RETURN p`

If you have any questions you're welcome!

Comment: no success. It only create `List`, but no `CONTACTS_LISTING`